# Arcpy replaceDataSource for different cases

Tags: arcpy, layer-file

I have a layer in my gdb file called **lines**. 
I also have a *.lyr file **lines-N** with symbology for the **lines** layer.
I need **lines-N** to have the same data source as **lines**, using `arcpy.replaceDataSource`.

My code:

```
kyl=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
desc=arcpy.Describe ("lines")
path = desc.path
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
      if lyr.name == "lines-N":
          if lyr.supports ("DATASOURCE"):
              lyr.replaceDataSource (path,"FILEGDB_WORKSPACE","",True)
```

produces this error:

```
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.replaceDataSource(*gp_fixargs((workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name, validate), True)))
ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to avoid manually adding the file path like so:

```
lyr.replaceDataSource (r "D:\Folder\file.gdb","FILEGDB_WORKSPACE","",True)
```

UPDATE:
*I'm running it from the ArcMap Python window to test it first, and then adding it to a script that performs similar operations on other layers.*
*ArcGIS version is 10.2.2*

Comment: How do you run your code? (from Python IDE, from Python window in ArcMap, as script tool?). I have a snippet of code that replicates yours and it works fine. Please update the question with this info + version of ArcGIS you have. One thing I strongly suggest avoiding - using strings for layer names in `arcpy.Describe`. There can be multiple feature layers created behind the scenes with various data sources, you can spend hours debugging. A better way - `cities_lyr = [lyr for lyr in mp.ListLayers(mxd,'cities')][0]` and then `path = arcpy.Describe(cities_lyr).path`

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, Just updated info as you requested. By the way, I have found that `path = desc.path` makes path of dataset if it exists, not just *.gdb file. Probably this caused error. Anyway you told that you've got a snippet, should it help in my case?

Comment: The `path` should contain only the folder/gdb, without the dataset name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this piece of code in Python window in ArcMap. You should have two layers - `lines` and `lines-N` in an ArcMap map document. They should refer to a feature class with the same name with each of the feature classes stored within two separate file geodatabases:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as mp

mxd = mp.MapDocument(r'current')
lines_lyr = [lyr for lyr in mp.ListLayers(mxd,'lines')][0]
path = arcpy.Describe(lines_lyr).path
print(path)
for lyr in mp.ListLayers(mxd,""):
    if lyr.name == 'lines-N':
        lyr.replaceDataSource(path,'FILEGDB_WORKSPACE','',True)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

After running this, you should immediately see that the `lines-N` map layer has now as the data source the file geodatabase used for the map layer `lines`.

Comment: The same error I mentioned before, path tool calculates path to to dataset, not gdb.  It could be right to use string scripts to delete one word after the last "\", but the thing is that feature classes can be stored directly in the root of gdb file.

Comment: Just found out! I used that: `pathgdb= path.split ("gdb")[0] + 'gdb'` and replaced it in your `replaceDataSource`